# float an image inside a list item

Tags: html, css

I am using an ordered list like the one below, I want to wrap the `<li>` number 2 text around the image, which should be placed to the right. At this point the image gets pushed behind the ordered list when adding `float: right:` to it.

How can I wrap the text around the image inside a `<li>` item in my ordered list?

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: li;
  /* Initiate a counter */
  list-style: none;
  /* Remove default numbering */
  *list-style: decimal;
  /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
  font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

ol ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
  /* Add some left margin for inner lists */
}

.rounded-list a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  *padding: .4em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rounded-list a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.rounded-list a:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.rounded-list a:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  background: #87ceeb;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: .3em solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.alignright {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ol class="rounded-list">
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum<img class="alignright" src="http://via.placeholder.com/290x290"></a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: overflow:auto on li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: li;
  /* Initiate a counter */
  list-style: none;
  /* Remove default numbering */
  *list-style: decimal;
  /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
  font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

ol ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
  /* Add some left margin for inner lists */
}

.rounded-list a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  *padding: .4em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rounded-list a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.rounded-list a:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.rounded-list a:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  background: #87ceeb;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: .3em solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

ol.rounded-list > li:nth-child(2):after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
ol.rounded-list > li:nth-child(2) a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.alignright {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ol class="rounded-list">
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href=""><img class="alignright" src="http://via.placeholder.com/290x290">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use float here -- and unlike many stack overflow questions about `float` you're actually using it for what it's intended for! -- you need two changes:

- Add `clear`s to prevent overlaps.  In this case it looks like it's necessary to add an explicit clearfix div; just putting clear on  the image itself (using `.alignright:after`) would mean the background color from the `<a>` doesn't always fully contain the image.
- Put the image before the text it's to be floated around, instead of at the end.

Other than those changes, this is identical to your existing code:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: li; /* Initiate a counter */
    list-style: none; /* Remove default numbering */
    *list-style: decimal; /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
    font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

ol ol {
    margin: 0 0 0 2em; /* Add some left margin for inner lists */
}



.rounded-list a{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
    *padding: .4em;
    margin: .5em 0;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: .3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;   
}

.rounded-list a:hover{
    background: #eee;
}

.rounded-list a:hover:before{
    transform: rotate(360deg);  
}

.rounded-list a:before{
    content: counter(li);
    counter-increment: li;
    position: absolute; 
    left: -1.3em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    background: #87ceeb;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    border: .3em solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 2em;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.alignright { float: right; }
.clearfix { clear:both }
```

```html
<ol class="rounded-list">
    <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img class="alignright" src="http://via.placeholder.com/290x290"> An example with a large image and not enough text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
    <div class="clearfix"></div></a></li>

    <li><a href=""><img class="alignright" src="http://via.placeholder.com/90x90"> An example with a smaller image. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <div class="clearfix"></div></a></li>

    <li><a href="">List item</a>
        <ol>
            <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
    <li><a href="">List item</a></li>                       
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `float` here...try to use `display:flex` in `<a>`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: li;
  /* Initiate a counter */
  list-style: none;
  /* Remove default numbering */
  *list-style: decimal;
  /* Keep using default numbering for IE6/7 */
  font: 15px 'trebuchet MS', 'lucida sans';
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

ol ol {
  margin: 0 0 0 2em;
  /* Add some left margin for inner lists */
}

.rounded-list a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: .4em .4em .4em 2em;
  *padding: .4em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.rounded-list a:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.rounded-list a:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.rounded-list a:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1.3em;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  background: #87ceeb;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  border: .3em solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 2em;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<ol class="rounded-list">
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum<img class="alignright" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">List sub item</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
  <li><a href="">List item</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of flexbox too -- but I think float is more appropriate for this situation.  Try yours with a smaller-sized or not-square image, it gets stretched to the full height of the list item...

Comment: (sorry, unintentional edit while checking that. I've rolled it back)

Comment: @DanielBeck good to here that you are a big fan of flexbox...then I think you will also aware about the `align-items` property of flex

Comment: Indeed I am! Glad to see you've added that to the answer, but note that it doesn't let the text wrap around smaller images like float does, which is probably the behavior that's called for in this case.    Float is *constantly* misused, so I totally understand where your knee-jerk rejection of it is coming from, but it's still a useful tool in the toolbox when used appropriately.  In this particular case I think it's the right tool to use.

Comment: @DanielBeck, he cannot use floats in this situation without re-arranging his HTML a bit.  The only way to achieve what his after with floats is to move img in front of the text of the second li.  If he's unwilling to move the img to the front, then his second best choice is to go with flex-box.  Cheers!

Comment: @Mers That's absolutely true, yes.